# How to control multiple React js components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-router-dom

I'm building a web application using React for front-end development, I'm really new to react but however i understand the main concepts.

Right now i have and index page which is rendered through my App.js file, here is some code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Link,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './Components/Login.component';
import Register from './Components/Register.component';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './App.css';


function App() {
return (

  <Router>
    <div className="container-fluid blue-container">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-lg-5 mx-auto justify-content-center" style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
          <img className="img-fluid img-fluid-logo mt-4" alt="logo" src="logo.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row justify-content-center d-flex align-items-center">
        <div className="col-lg-5 mx-auto justify-content-center d-flex align-items-center" style={{marginTop:"120px",textAlign:"center"}}>
          <Link to="/Login" className="btn btn-primary" style={{marginRight:"10px"}}><i className="fas fa-lock"></i> Se connecter</Link>
          <Link to="/Register" className="btn btn-primary"><i className="fas fa-lock"></i> S'inscrire</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/Login">
        <Login />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/Register">
        <Register />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>


 );
}

export default App;
```

And as you can see i'm using two Components in two different files, Login and Register.
Everything is working fine, but the issue i have is when i click the **Link** the application renders the **h1** that supposed to be rendered, but the thing is that it shows up **AFTER** my main container, here is the image :

(The logo and the two LINKS are in the app.js code)

[image]

My question is : is there any way to control the first component to be removed (logo and the two links) after the **LINK** click event happens and render only login/register forms without using Javascript or jquery ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You should fully complete your React training and if any questions arise **after** than it would be a good idea to ask, but first learn the fundamentals. Try Youtube, Egghead..complete a full *up-to-date* course.

Comment: I did complete Reactjs essential training on Linkedin Learning, but the courses contains only syntax and concept tutorials !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this. I'd suggest putting your main container (i.e. your logo and whatever else you want in your landing page) in another component (let's call it `Main`), then render that `Main` component in separate route like such:

```
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Main />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/Login">
        <Login />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/Register">
        <Register />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Specifying `exact path="/"` means that the pattern will only match if the route is *exactly* "/". i.e. it will match with `myApp.com` but not with `myApp.com/Login`. Now, your `Main` component would look like:

```
function Main() {
   return(<div className="container-fluid blue-container">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-lg-5 mx-auto justify-content-center" style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
          <img className="img-fluid img-fluid-logo mt-4" alt="logo" src="logo.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row justify-content-center d-flex align-items-center">
        <div className="col-lg-5 mx-auto justify-content-center d-flex align-items-center" style={{marginTop:"120px",textAlign:"center"}}>
          <Link to="/Login" className="btn btn-primary" style={{marginRight:"10px"}}><i className="fas fa-lock"></i> Se connecter</Link>
          <Link to="/Register" className="btn btn-primary"><i className="fas fa-lock"></i> S'inscrire</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>)
}
```

Comment: When i type the URL "localhost:3000/Login" it renders only what 's in the Login component, but when i click the LINK in the MAIN component as you said, nothing happens.
P.S : my app.js file contains only Router, Switch, Route and the components, meanwhile every component is in a different file.

Answer (score 0):

Make it another React component so you can use conditional rendering. It's basically rendering a part of your UI based on a value controlled by the state of your component or by a props.

Check this tuto out https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html. They explain pretty nicely how it works.